# Maven Standard Directory Layout

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am trying to get the Maven standard directory layout on my Eclipse project with the expected

```
src/main/java   
src/main/resources
src/test/java   
src/test/resources
```

However, all I am seeing after building the project is the following:

[image]

Can someone give me some specific instructions as to what I need to do to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Have you installed or updated the [M2Eclipse plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/)?

Comment: "all I'm seeing"... what do you expect to see? what's wrong? your build seems to be successful.

Comment: I believe so Eclipse acts like its already there as I can't proceed with the next button when i select it

Comment: Before you can use M2Eclipse on Java Project you need to convert it to Maven. Use `Configure->Convert to Maven Project`.

Comment: Sorry for moving comments. Use `Maven->Update project...` and if it does not work, use @Daniel's suggestion: remove `.project` and `.classpath` files and then import the project through `File->Import->Exisitng Maven Project`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can deduce from your screen-shots

- the Eclipse project is correctly configured to be a Maven project (it has the Maven nature - that can be seen by the `M` icon on the project folder icon)
- the M2Eclipse plugin is correctly up-to-date

Now, the first error is that your POM is incorrect. You should remove the declaration `<sourceDirectory>`.

Then my guess is that you arrived at your current situation because, in Eclipse, you created a "Java Project" and then converted it to a "Maven Project" by right-clicking and selecting "Configure > Convert to Maven Project" (what makes me thinks that is your current source folder being `src`, which is the default after creating a "Java Project").

What you seem to be missing is a clean refresh of your project. You should right-click the project, go into "Maven > Update Project...", and click "OK". This should resolve your problem.

If this does not work for some reason, I suggest you remove your current project (from the workspace and the content on disk) and, instead of creating a "Java Project", create a "Maven Project", by going to "File > New... > Maven Project". The M2Eclipse plugin will kick in and this new project will be correctly configured.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<sourceDirectory>` tags. You are using the defaults and these do not need to be declared.

Also, as the esteemed @Tunaki mentioned, use the M2Eclipse (m2e) plugin or right-click the project and select "Enable Dependency Management". If you are using Eclipse Luna or later, m2e is already included. If you don't do this, you'll be able to build just fine from the Command Prompt, but Eclipse will be confused.

Comment: I tried loading a new project since I am just beginning and still have the same issue, forgive if the question seems elementary but when i right click on my project i don't see "Enable Dependency Management" I have Eclipse Mars so I believee that m2e is already on here as i am unable to install it from the configuration feature.

Comment: @MichałGrzejszczak According to the screenshot, it already has the Maven nature (look at the `M` icon)

Comment: Or you could try to delete the project (but not its contents) and re-import the project by selecting "Import existing Maven project" though the Import wizard.